# intersection code that prints the intersection of two arrays ( posting lists )

Tags: c++, arrays, intersection

**I wrote this code to print the intersection of two arrays ( posting lists) using dev c++
the problem that when I run the program nothing is printed
can you help ?**

I need to know where is the problem 
and what if I wanted to use cout instead of printf?

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

// Intersecting two postings lists (a “merge” algorithm) 
// and I will assume that the two posting listst are sorted Ascendingly
// I will suppose that the first posting list is an array wich 
// have n elements I wil name it fistPost
// I will suppose that the second posting list is an array wich have
// m elements I will name it secondPost

int main()
{
    int firstPost[] ={3,5,7,8,13,15,30,34};
    int secondPost[]={1,5,7,9,11,15,20,34,35};
    int i,j=0;

    int n = sizeof(firstPost)/sizeof(firstPost[0]);
    int m = sizeof(secondPost)/sizeof(secondPost[0]);

    while(i<n && j<m)
    { 
        if (firstPost[i]<secondPost[j])
            i++;
        else if (firstPost[i]>secondPost[j])
            j++;
        else  if (firstPost[i]=secondPost[j])
        {
            printf ("%i", secondPost[j++]);
            i++;      
        }
    }        
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wrote the code using c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't initialized 'i' to 0, hence its taking some garbage value and not executing the while loop.

change int i, j = 0;
to int i = 0, j = 0;

Comment: thank you it all right 
finshed my code now

Answer (score 1):

change this  `printf ("%i", secondPost[j++]);`

to

`printf ("%d", secondPost[j++]);`